# Update only the latest array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to update the `array2` only and same values for `array1`. I wrote the following code,

```
array1 = [4232,3423,325,23421];
array2 = array1;
array2[0] = array2[0]/10;
array2[1] = array2[1]/100;
array2[2] = array2[2]/10;
console.log(array1, array2);
```

But the console shows both `array1` and `array2` are updated. How can I update the values of the `array2` only?

Comment: Use a library like [Lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.clonedeep) to deep clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a complex array, I think you can try `deep copy` method as following,

```js
array1 = [4232,[24234,2324,[43,234]],3423,325,23421];

array2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));

array2[0] = array2[0]/10;
array2[1][2][1] = array2[1][2][1]/100;
array2[2] = array2[2]/10;
console.log(array1, array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the array, or else both use the same reference.

```
array2 = [...array1];
```

If you have a nested array, you can do it this way [[source]](https://dev.to/samanthaming/how-to-deep-clone-an-array-in-javascript-3cig):

```
clone = (items) => items.map(item => Array.isArray(item) ? clone(item) : item);
array2 = clone(array1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should shallow copy the array:

```js
array1 = [4232,3423,325,23421];
array2 = [...array1];
array2[0] = array2[0]/10;
array2[1] = array2[1]/100;
array2[2] = array2[2]/10;
console.log(array1, array2);
```

Comment: Sorry, This is not working for the complex array-like, `array1 =[4232,[24234,2324,[43,234]],3423,325,23421]`. Actually  I want to update inner element. I mean `array1[1][2][0]`.